# osx 10.10 force 32 bit

Tags: macos, 32-bit

I am trying to start my OS X 10.10 in 32 bit, but with no success:

- First I tried it by keeping 3 + 2 pressed during start up
- Then I tried by the following command: `sudo systemsetup -setkernelbootarchitecture i386`

In both cases all I get `RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64` by running `uname -a`

Is it possible at all to force 32 bit on OS X 10.10?

- This is my processor: i7-2675QM
- I have hardware drivers that only support 32 bit for AWUS036H

Is there another way to use that hardware with 10.10?

Comment: Would appreciate to know the reason for the down vote

Comment: Don't know why you were down voted as your question is a legitimate one, although you probably could have Googled and found out that 10.6 was the last 32-bit version of OS X.  Anyway, I up voted strictly on the basis there appeared to be no valid reason for the down vote.

Comment: What's the real problem to be solved? Once you get booted in 32 what are you trying to do? What makes you think the kernel is even compiled as a 32 bit executable anymore?

Comment: I think it would help if you clarified what "AWUS036H" *is*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.alfa.com.tw/products_show.php?pc=34&ps=92, AWUS036H is only supported up to OSX 10.6. If you need a kext or similar to use the device, you will be out of luck with 64bit only versions of OSX (which means 10.7 and higher).

Comment: I wonder if you could run 10.6 in emulation and pass the USB port directly to the virtual machine and use the hardware? It would be a lot of work and probably cheaper to just buy another device, but sometimes doing this "for reasons" is a learning journey.

Answer (score 2):

Why?

All OS since Snow Leopard are 64 bit only.

Comment: I have a piece of hardware which is only 32 bit compatible AWUS036H.